# GET UID from firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to get the `uid` when i trigger the storage events?

I want create a thumb when the image is uploaded in to firebase storage and then update the url of the user image profile in database...

```
exports.uploadphoto = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Two Options**

You could store your image to a path that contains the uId
then use `event.data.name` to get the file path

OR

Add it to the custom metadata when you upload, then access in cloud functions by:

```
const metadata = event.data.metadata
const uId = metadata.uId
```

*uId* can be whatever you call it when you upload.

**Uploading with custom metadata docs**

iOS: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/file-metadata

Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata

Web: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata